# Getting rid of old artwork and sketchbooks?

Tags: drawing, painting

My folks died a couple of years ago and we had to empty the house and do all that sad stuff. I had 40 years of artwork in their attic and I brought it all to my studio to "sort out". Three years later I am still tripping over all of it and I am trying to figure out what to do.

None of it is "worth" anything. I've been an artist for most of my life and have had my little successes but no one is ever going to be assembling a [Catalogue raisonné](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalogue_raisonn%C3%A9) on me :-)

So what to do with it all? It's mostly works on paper, some matted, most not. And LOTS of sketchbooks with really bad stuff. I barely have any nostalgic tie to it all – but I wonder if I will regret "some day" having tossed it all out?

Comment: Hi spring, welcome to Arts&Crafts. This is not the right platform to ask this type of question. I can redirect you to our [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38932/the-studio), and maybe you will be able to discuss it more. Otherwise, I'd try Reddit (maybe [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Art/)). I hope this helps.

Comment: Im so sorry to hear that. Have you posted your artwork in some website? maybe that would make some profit. Those little successes can be worth something, because it the original paint. What you can also do is rent a storage, you ca put them all in there to save some space. I see throwing artwork away a loss, you spent countless hours working on them to just throw them away. I recommend selling the original paints (if you don't want them) you can just post it in some website(people can buy copies of it) think of it as "assets".